# Reversed " and @ keys Lenovo T430

Tags: lenovo-laptop

How do I swap the <kbd>@</kbd> and <kbd>"</kbd> key functions on my Lenovo T430? They are currently reversed. I have already checked the keyboard language is set to English UK. Apart from this one small glitch, everything is working fine.

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: That sounds like a typical Mac/PC keyboard issue. UK (& possibly other) keyboards have shift/2 for @ on Mac, shift/' for @ on PC & vice versa - I've just learned to live with it, whichever OS I'm using.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Windows 7 pro, but I think apologies are due from me. I realised after posting the question that the keys are functioning correctly for a UK English keyboard. It's just that the two keys in question are printed with the wrong symbols. I'm guessing it's an American keyboard (I have the @ on the 2 key and I have ' and " sharing the same key next to L.) 
I think this is just a case of sticking a label on the two keys concerned. Sorry to have troubled you all.
Regards, Tim

Comment: You won't have a £ over 3 either, then.